# Lazarus cannot find Indy unit

Tags: indy, freepascal, lazarus

I've downloaded the latest version of Indy for lazarus (10.2.0.3) and it is installed into my Windows XP. On the top of the IDE I can see the tabs about Indy but when I type `IdFTP` or `IdHTTP` into uses, Lazarus 1.0.2 gives the error "Can't find unit IdFTP (or IdHTTP) used by [program]". I've checked the Other File Units in compiler path but fpc is already included. What could I do?

Comment: Did you try the latest Lazarus version? (1.0.8)

Comment: The latest version of Indy is 10.6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the Indy packages added to the "required packages" in the project inspector?

In Lazarus you need to add packages to the project (as dependency), and the IDE will automatically add the relevant paths.